# the connectionstring property has not been initialized. c# Access database

Tags: c#, ms-access, connection-string

I cant seem to solve it i am trying to connect to my access database but i just cant and keep getting error. can someone help me out

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form

    {
        private OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
            string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);
            OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb;User Id=admin; Password=;");


        }

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form3 f3 = new Form3(); // Instantiate a Form3 object.
            f3.Show(); // Show Form3 and
            this.Close(); // closes the Form2 instance
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            try
            {

                connection.Open();
                OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
                command.Connection = connection;
                command.CommandText= "INSERT into Dataaa ([FirstName],[LastName],[ICNO],[Address],[Loan],[Percent],[Payback],[StartDate],[EndDate],[Monthly],[PaymentType],[Remark]) values ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text + "','" + textBox7.Text + "','" + textBox8.Text + "','" + textBox9.Text + "','" + textBox10.Text + "','" + textBox11.Text + "','" + textBox12.Text + "')";

                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Details have been Saved.");

            }
            catch (Exception ex)

            {

                MessageBox.Show("error " + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
            connection.Close();
            }

        }
```

Comment: can you post the error message?

Comment: @M.Schena  the connectionstring property has not been initialized

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you never pass a connection string to the `connection` property so that's why the exception is being thrown.

Currently you are initializing a local variable inside the constructor which doesn't get used. All that is needed is to remove the local variable and simply initialize the property with the correct connection string.

To fix the issue simply change your constructor method to the follow:

```
public Form2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    string executable = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
    string path = (System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(executable));
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetData("DataDirectory", path);

    this.connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb;User Id=admin; Password=;");
}
```

And remove the initialization on the property so it's the following:

```
private OleDbConnection connection;
```

As Owen Pauling said you are open for SQL injection attacks so I'd strongly recommend you browse over this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev) to stop yourself from being open to attack. Mainly looking at the parameterised queries section of the article.

Answer (score 0):

You have both a private variable (named "connection") for and a local variable (named "connect") for the `OleDbConnection`. You are initializing the latter with the connection string but using the former to run your command.

In your Form2 method change:

```
OleDbConnection connect = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb;User Id=admin; Password=;");
```

to:

```
connection = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Database.accdb;User Id=admin; Password=;");
```

Also use query parameters for your command so that you are not open to SQL injection attacks.